# Spring AOP doesn't work with @Component class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I'm using Spring AOP for exception handling but there is one point that I guess my component class is out of Spring Proxy so Spring AOP annotation that I created doesn't work in that class.

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MGRuleConfig {

    private final GRepository repository;

    private final GInitializer initializer;

    private final GMapper mapper;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mRules")
    public List<GRules> mRules(){
        SSRule rule1 = new SSRule();
        CSRule rule2 = new CSRule();
        MPRule rule3 = new MPRule();
        EGRule rule4 = new EGRule();

        return List.of(rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4);
    }

    @Bean
    public GService gService() {
        return new MGServiceImpl(repository, initializer, mapper);
    }
}
```

Then I have this service;

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MGServiceImpl implements GService {

............

    @Override
    public GaDTO executeRules(String gId, Integer pN) {
        Ga ga = repository.findById(gId);
        GaDTO gaDTO = mapper.toDTO(ga);
        List<GaRules> mRules = (List<GaRules>) applicationContext.getBean("mRules");
        mRules.forEach(rule -> rule.apply(gaDTO, pN));
        repository.save(mapper.toEntity(gaDTO));
        return gaDTO;
    }
```

I need to put my exception handling annotation into that **apply** method but aspect doesn't work in that method.

```
@Component
public class SSRule implements GaRules {

    @Override
    @IPException
    public void apply(GaDTO gaDTO, Integer pN) {
        PDTO p1 = gaDTO.getP1();
        PDTO p2 = gaDTO.getP2();

        if (PTEnum.P_1.equals(gaDTO.getPT())) {
            sS(gaDTO, pN, p1, p2);
        } else {
            sS(gaDTO, pN, p2, p1);
        }
    }
```

Annotation doesn't work in there. Here's my aspect class;

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class IPExceptionAspect {

    @Around("execution(public * c.m.s.r.i.SSRule.apply(..)) && " +
            "@annotation(c.m.s.i.a.IPException)")
    public Object checkIP(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        pjp.proceed();
        return pjp;
    }

}
```

So, what should I do to make **IPException** annotation and my **Spring AOP** work and why doesn't it work?

Comment: It doesn't work because the rule instances aren't beans, they are part of a list that is a bean. Instead make them instances.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: As stated create an `@Bean` method for those rules, and either just get all of them from the context (spring iwll put them in a list for you) or if the order is important inject the dependencies in the list yourself (but not creating new onces, by refercing the previously created instances from the bean methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code, you are creating instances of those rules yourself **inside** a bean method and expose them as a `List`. Which means the bean is of type `List` not your own `SSRule` and thus it won't work.

Instead make an `@Bean` method, or use the detected instance to inject into the list. As your `SSRule` is annotated you will already have an instance, just inject that into your `@Bean` method.

```java
Bean
@Qualifier("mRules")
public List<GRules> mRules(SSRule rule1){
    CSRule rule2 = new CSRule();
    MPRule rule3 = new MPRule();
    EGRule rule4 = new EGRule();

   return List.of(rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4);
}
```

Now you will get the Spring managed instance which will have AOP applied.

Although I would hardly call this AOP as it is too specific for one class (not really crosscutting in that regard).